# vnstat showing two entries for september

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line

I run `vnstat -m`, and I get the following output:

```
user@computer:~$ vnstat -m

wlan0  /  monthly

   month        rx      |     tx      |    total    |   avg. rate
------------------------+-------------+-------------+---------------
  Aug '12       3.65 GB |   477.93 MB |     4.12 GB |   12.90 kbit/s
  Sep '12      16.49 GB |     1.23 GB |    17.72 GB |   57.34 kbit/s
  Sep '12      12.90 GB |     3.50 GB |    16.41 GB |   53.10 kbit/s
  Oct '12      15.22 GB |     6.09 GB |    21.31 GB |   66.75 kbit/s
  Nov '12       8.76 GB |   856.91 MB |     9.59 GB |   31.05 kbit/s
  Dec '12       1.82 GB |   204.87 MB |     2.02 GB |   17.96 kbit/s
------------------------+-------------+-------------+---------------
estimated       5.16 GB |      579 MB |     5.73 GB |
```

Why are there two entries for September?  Does this look like a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a bug to me. I've been using vnstat for years, and I've never seen behavior like that. Report it.